# single array element gets omitted by jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

In a shortcut,
I have an array of ID's, for example:

```
var positions = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
```

Then i have a function which applies some actions to the elements with ID's specified in the array:

```
for (var i = positions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(positions[i]);
    $('#'+positions[i]).addClass('disabled');
};
```

Now the thing is, the `console.log()` lists all four ID's correctly, but only elements with ID's 'b', 'c', 'e' get affected, while 'd' doesn't. They're all the same section elements, with the same kind of content.

Comment: let's see your html code . may be it is some typo in "d" element

Comment: In your loop, do `console.log(positions[i], $('#'+positions[i]).length);` and tell us what that shows.

Comment: Why not simply: `for (var i=0; i<positions.length; i++){` ?

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/w9aM4/ Check your html like @Cherniv suggested

Comment: Yup, it was a typo. I had duplicated id of value 'd'. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.